# get select value angularjs without ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<select ng-model="list">
<option value="1">first</option>
<option value="2">next</option>
</select>
```

How to get selected option using angularjs? Most of the case I see they use ng-repeat but how to get selected option when I didn't use ng-repeat?

I `console.log($scope.list)` I got undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example from the Angular Documentation: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/YcnLSCJJ4rQT5kbousln?p=preview)

It shows how it is done.

```
<select ng-model="model.id" convert-to-number>
  <option value="0">Zero</option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
</select>
```

Link Updated!

Comment: Upps.. Sorry.. I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-options.

See the [the plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/fohkBc1ScPprBMiOGS6b?p=preview)

```
<select ng-model="model" ng-options="item.value as item.display for item in someOptions">
```

```
$scope.someOptions = [{display: 'one', value: 1},{display: 'two', value: 2} ,{display:'three', value:3}]
```